# How to set the screen location for a new window under Wayland?

Tags: gnome, configuration, window, customization, wayland

Under Xorg if I opened the System Monitor and then dragged it so that it was on the right-hand side of the screen sort of 'docked' there, then when I closed it an opened it again it would remember the last location of that application and open it there.

However, under Wayland, there is no such feature due to how it is written for security. But I really like having the System Monitor on the right-side of the screen kind of 'docked' there (as it is when you drag and release the window right on the edge of the screen), but it by default usually (sometimes in the past on previous installations I convinced it not to) opens on the left-hand side of the screen.

So I was wondering if there is any way at all to set the screen coordinates or location for an application in the `.desktop` file or any way of doing this under Wayland for when you launch the application? Or is this something that is no longer possible under Wayland due to how it designed to work?